# Stackframe of function with pointer as paramter

Tags: c, pointers, stack, buffer-overflow, stack-frame

Consider the following scenario in the programming language C:

```
void f(char* name, int age){
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char* name = argv[1];
    int x = 1
    f(name, x);
}
```

How would the stackframe of `f()` look like in this situation? I'm asking myself if the name is really pushed to the stack, since it is a pointer...

Is the following correct?

```
---high address---
argv[1]
1
return address
saved EBP
---low address---
```

Or without `argv[1]`?

Comment: Why not try it out yourself and find out?

Comment: What stack frames look like depends on the Application Binary Interface (ABI) used, and you have not stated what ABI is being used or what platform you are targeting or what tools you are using. In any case, in order for a function to receive the value of an argument, the value of the argument must be passed to the function. Whether it is a pointer or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @RyanZhang How is that possible? Is there a website, which shows me the actual stack of a C code?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't know what an ABI is, just assume an ordinary new laptop with x86 architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm asking myself if the name is really pushed to the stack

A pointer stores the memory address of what it points to. If you are passing a pointer as an argument to a function, you are passing a **copy** of such memory address, and thus not the content itself.

```c
void myFunction(char* ptrNameCopy)
{
  printf("%p\n", &ptrNameCopy); // "#300", the address of 'ptrNameCopy'
  printf("%p\n",  ptrNameCopy); // "#100", the copy of 'ptrName' content
  printf("%s\n",  ptrNameCopy); // "program", the content at address #100, pointed by 'ptrName'
} 

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char* ptrName = argv[0];
  printf("%p\n", ptrName);      // "#100", 'ptrName' content

  myFunction(ptrName);
  return 0;
}
```

An illustration before returning from myFunction.

```
at myFunction,
+---------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
| Address | What        | Content                             |
+---------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
| #300    | ptrNameCopy | #100 (aka. copy of ptrName content) |
+---------+------------+--------------------------------------+

at main,
+---------+-------------+--------------------------------+
| Address | What        | Content                        |
+---------+-------------+--------------------------------+
| #100    | argv[0]     | "./program"                    |
| #200    | ptrName     | #100 (aka. address of argv[0]) |
+---------+-------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Very nice explanation!! Now I understand passed by value and passed by reference much better!!

Comment: No problem, let me know if there is something else! In time, always remember that in C it is always "pass by value", what you referred to as "pass by reference" it is actually "passing by value a copy of the memory address that points to the original location, but not a copy of the object itself" (notice in my answer that whenever this happens, the word "copy" was used).

Comment: Yes exactly, that changed my view of pointers somehow (in a good manner) :D Have a nice weekend!